# Android : How to set content while calling a new activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new at Android development, and I would like to know something.

I know that, if I want to go to another activity I have to do :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But if my AnotherActivity contains for example a String or any variable, that I want to set before reaching it, how to do ? I would like to do something like :

```
AnotherActivity activity = new AnotherActivity();
activity.setValue("myValue");
// call the activity ?
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra_name", "extra_value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in `AnotherActivity`:

```
String extra_value = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_name", "default_extra_value");
```